# Is there a way to create visual page informations in php, javascript and css pages?

Tags: javascript, php, css, header-files

Is there a way to create visual page informations in php, javascript and css pages like in the image? I think script's author did not write one by one with figures[image]

Comment: can't we put that information as an image in html?

Comment: But this is not image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just ASCII art. There are countless ways of generating it - I don't know of any particular way of doing it with PHP, but this stuff is (literally) older than the Internet.

Search for ASCII Art Generator or similar, that might get you some better results.